# Redefining index values in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

There seem to be plenty of other questions about indexing Pandas DataFrames, but I have not found a way to do the type of changes I want. If I have a DF which looks likes

```
                Value
 Index1 Index2
 0      1       1.1
 1      2       1.2
 2      3       2.4
 3      1       1.3
 4      2       2.2
 5      3       3.1
```

I don't need all of index1 to be unique. I would rather have something like

```
                Value
 Index1 Index2
 0      1       1.1
 0      2       1.2
 0      3       2.4
 1      1       1.3
 1      2       2.2
 1      3       3.1
```

Is there a way to do this? I think the easiest way is to apply a function of dividing by index1 values by 3, but not sure how you apply a function to an index. Perhaps though pandas has it's own methods for redefining index values to have groupings like this which are still unique when you consider both indexes?

Answer (score 5):

```
import io
import pandas as pd
text = '''\
 Index1 Index2 Value
 0      1       1.1
 1      2       1.2
 2      3       2.4
 3      1       1.3
 4      2       2.2
 5      3       3.1'''

df = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO(text), sep='\s+', index_col=[0, 1])
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [(item[0] // 3, item[1]) for item in df.index],
    names=df.index.names)    
print(df)
```

yields

```
               Value
Index1 Index2       
0      1         1.1
       2         1.2
       3         2.4
1      1         1.3
       2         2.2
       3         3.1
```